# Is it safe to run more than 1K threads in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

I am making a program which tries to get all the possible outcomes. The threads in the program generate more threads (a little over a thousand). I am really bad at multithreading, I fear that the generation of threads won't stop. I am using the eclipse IDE which has a terminate button, will this stop all the running thread, if not is there any other way? Can the JVM handle this?

Comment: yes, if you terminate the `JVM` all the threads will stop running

Comment: what is the benefit of making this high number of threads ? (you will see performance degradation )

Comment: You can run 1000 or more threads, but in the end you don't have 1000+ cores to run each individual thread on

Comment: Sounds like you really want an executor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Clicking the terminate button in an eclipse launched JVM will halt that JVM, and that will stop all of the running threads (just like killing the JVM process).

As for running one thousand threads, I wouldn't recommend it... that sounds like a really slow approach (since each thread can only run a maximum of ~n/1000th of the time on `n` CPU cores).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is no restrictions to open 1000 or more thread in Java programming language. However, the problem is it will slow down the works.

Do you know how the thread works? Thread just creates an environment with the help of the OS so that the application user can feel that the programs are running parallel. But, the actual scenario is different. The computer having a single core processor can handle one operation at an instant. Our OS just sends operations one after one, so that we the user can feel that they are running in parallel.

For example, let us consider a three threaded application. Each of its thread has a for loop. First thread adds numbers inside the loop and keep the result in a variable named result1, second thread multiplies numbers inside the loop and keep the result in a variable named result2, and third thread subtracts numbers inside the loop and keep the result in a variable named result3.

Now, if all these threads are started at the same instant and let all has same priority then the OS will send instructions one after one. If can send a number to add with result1. In the next instant, it can send a number to multiply with result2. In the next instant, it can send a number to subtract with result3. In the next instant, it can again add.

That means, actually a single core processor cannot compute three computation simultaneously. It compute one computation and make pause the remaining ones and go through in this way.

I think, now you understand why running 1000 thread will slow down the whole process. If the performance is not issue in the mentioned task and you just need the output you can run 1000+ thread.

But, if you need an improved performance you have to think something else. Have you hard about [Map Reduce](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/mapreduce-osdi04.pdf)? Implementing map reduce by [Hadoop](https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/) framework you can get better performance in these type of issues. However, first you have to design your problem in map reduce frame. And this framework will compute you task in parallel with the help of more than one computers.

Another solution can be setting priority. In java you can set priorities in a thread.You can give critical tasks high priorities than simpler tasks. If your problem's tasks can be distinguished by high and low priorities tasks it will make the performance better definitely.